# No com.sun.tools.javac in JDK7

Tags: java, java-6, java-7

I'm using JDK7 and Eclipse Indiago in Windows 7 64-bit. I set environment variable JAVA_HOME to F:\JDK7 and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin in path. It's my sample code:

```
com.sun.tools.javac.Main m1 = new com.sun.tools.javac.Main();
m1.compile(source);
```

Error I get:

> Type com.sun.tools cannot be resolved to a
>   type

Why there is no com.sun.tools ? What's the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like you are using Eclipse. By default Eclipse only imports JRE jars, not the ones from the JDK.

Solution 1:

1. Go to Eclipse preferences (on Windows: Window-->Preferences)
2. Open the preference Java-->Installed JREs
3. Select your JRE and press edit
4. Use "Add external jars" to include the tools.jar (found in JDK_HOME/lib)

Solution 2:

Edit your project build path and add an external library: tools.jar found in JDK_HOME/lib

Comment: After I did as you said.There is another error: ` Description Resource Path Location Type
Access restriction: The constructor Main() is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\tools.jar Compiler.java /imageJ/source/ij/plugin line 58 Java Problem
 `

Comment: Check you compiler settings in Eclipse. You probably have some rules saying that restricted API should be reported as Errors (Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Compiler-->Errors/Warnings see the section about "Deprecated and restricted API")

Answer (score 8):

You are better off using the [JavaCompiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html), rather than attemtping to call javac directly which is in tools.jar The API will add this for you if you use it.

Comment: I'm going to compile really old style code. You are right anyway. thanks

Answer (score 1):

javac is in the JDK bin directory, but not the JRE bin.

I had a similar problem and it turned out that by mistake I had set my JAVA_HOME variable to the JRE instead of the JDK, i.e.,

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60 instead of 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

Because I "knew" that I had copied the correct directory name, it took me ages to see those two different characters and fix the problem.